# Migrated WindowsPhone8 build stuck on the Splash screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

Migrated worklight 6.1 project to Mobile First 7.1.
Using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160801-2314

Build app to work remote Mobile First server by giving correct Server path and Context path.

Windows build with 6.1 is working fine where as migrated windows build is stuck on the Splash screen. Waited for more then 10 minutes but not loaded landing page.

Cross checked contents of wlclient.properties file. Found its contents are generated correctly.

Find below for debug logs while deploying app on device from Visual Studio

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{92FAFB73-DACB-497F-B1B2-7266DCF1FC5D}\Install\RBL_iBank.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{92FAFB73-DACB-497F-B1B2-7266DCF1FC5D}\Install\WLWPNativeLib.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{92FAFB73-DACB-497F-B1B2-7266DCF1FC5D}\Install\WPCordovaClassLib.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Adding feature.value=PushPlugin
Adding feature.value=Battery
Adding feature.value=Camera
Adding feature.value=Contacts
Adding feature.value=Device
Adding feature.value=Accelerometer
Adding feature.value=Compass
Adding feature.value=Notification
Adding feature.value=File
Adding feature.value=FileTransfer
Adding feature.value=Globalization
Adding feature.value=InAppBrowser
Adding feature.value=Media
Adding feature.value=NetworkStatus
Adding feature.value=SplashScreen
Adding feature.value=Vibration
Adding feature.value=DeviceAuth
Adding feature.value=Push
Adding feature.value=WifiPlugin
Adding feature.value=WLApplicationBar
Adding feature.value=WLBusyIndicator
Adding feature.value=WLCustomDialog
Adding feature.value=WLOpenURL
Adding feature.value=WLGeolocationPlugin
Adding feature.value=WLNativePage
Adding feature.value=WLDirectUpdatePlugin
Adding feature.value=DeviceInfo
Adding feature.value=Badge
Adding feature.value=StoragePlugin
Adding feature.value=WLNativeXHRPlugin
Adding feature.value=WLSplashScreen
Adding feature.value=SecurityPlugin
Adding feature.value=WLApp
Adding feature.value=StatusBar
Adding feature.value=WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: ac863433-291b-45e8-a19a-22f803e652dc
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Device.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

Followed below steps in migration

```
    1) Exported 6.1 Hybrid project as Archive file
    2) Imported 6.1 project in MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160801-2314
    3) Refresh and clean project was done
    4) Deleted all files in bin folder and redeployed adapter and app. 
    5) Checked all apps in simulator and found all are working fine.
    6) Enabled Build application work with different mobile first server and entered correct values to Server and context path
    7) Repeated steps 3 and 4
    8) All deployable files generated in bin folder given for deployment team to deploy on Mobile First server
    10) Got feedback from deployment team like wlapp file deployment success with one warning "It is recommended to use extended app authenticity"
    11) Copied windowsphone8 folder from workspace to Windows machine. Opened project in Visual Studio. 
    12) Cross checked wlclient.properties file contents found correct.
    13) Clean solution and build on device 
    14) Found app struct in splash screen. Waited for more then 10 minutes. Clean solution and re-deploy on device on several times on Visual Studio but no use. Restarted Visual Studio and re-opened project on Visaul Studio still found no use.
```

Note: Migrated Android Build is working fine on device for remote server.

Comment: Which server you are trying to connect with ? (6.1 or 7.1) and also can you let me on what steps you followed for migration ?

Comment: Am trying connect with 7.1 remote server. Edited question for Followed migration steps.

Comment: Please let me know if PMR is expecting for this issue

Comment: As with the iOS issue you're facing, I believe the same is needed here.

Comment: Seems like the same migration error as in your other question. Please open a PMR.